# How saxon:attribute-order works?

Tags: xslt, xls, saxon

I'm trying to reorder the attributes of a tag using the Serialization parameter "saxon:attribute-order" but I could not make it works, what am I missing?

Source file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <list>
        <span class="pagebreak" name="1" title="ONE">Test</span>
        <span class="nobreak" name="X" title="X">Test</span>
        <span class="pagebreak" name="2" title="TWO">Test</span>
        <span class="pagebreak" name="3" title="THREE">Test</span>
        <span class="pagebreak" name="4" title="FOUR">Test</span>
        <span class="nobreak" name="Y" title="Y">Test</span>
        <span class="pagebreak" name="5" title="FIVE">Test</span>
    </list>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="saxon">

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" saxon:attribute-order="title name class * xml:space"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="*/span[contains(@class, 'pagebreak')]" />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/span[contains(@class, 'pagebreak')]">
 <xsl:copy-of select="." />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<span class="pagebreak" name="1" title="ONE">Test</span>
<span class="pagebreak" name="2" title="TWO">Test</span>
<span class="pagebreak" name="3" title="THREE">Test</span>
<span class="pagebreak" name="4" title="FOUR">Test</span>
<span class="pagebreak" name="5" title="FIVE">Test</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown us, so the problem is somewhere in what you haven't shown us...

Perhaps you're using Saxon-HE which doesn't recognise extension attributes.

Perhaps you're sending the output to a destination other than a serializer?

Try it from the command line, with the -t option, and see if that works, and then we can take it from there.

Comment: Yes, you are right my current version is SAXON 9.1.0.8 from Saxonica (build 102723) and it does not support this extension attribute.
Thank you.